# Trigger input validation error with JQuery on materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I know it's a pretty lame question, but I couldn't find it in documentation and neither around forums.

I have this HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <label for="CEP">CEP <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input class="validate" id="CEP" name="CEP" required="required" type="text" />
</div>
```

I don't have a form for this field because I will post it via ajax.
Before I send I want to check if it have a value, so I will do something like this

```
if($("#CEP").val() === '')
{
    //trigger error and return
}
```

The problem is: I want to trigger the validation error correct using JQuery. but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple.
Just try:

...

```
if($("#CEP").val() === '')
{
    $('#CEP').addClass('invalid');
}
```

And also add the error message on the input when the validation is wrong:

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <label for="CEP">CEP <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input class="validate" id="CEP" name="CEP" required="required" type="text" />
    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Wrong Credentials!"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `$("CEP")` is not a valid selector for your example as it will select elements having tag as `CEP`= > `<CEP>`

To select elements using `id` attribute, use `#`

Try this:

```
if($("#CEP").val() === '')
{
    //trigger error and return
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a miss edit, that was not the problem. The problem is that I don't find how to trigger the validation anywere.